# Create StateFlow from SharedFlow

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an object where I wish to create hot StateFlow objects from a filtered cold SharedFlow. The intent is that the SharedFlow is an event channel of data changes, but all data can be retrieved to get the current state. This means for a given field, I can find the current state, and then monitor the SharedFlow to get state changes.

I would like to provide an API that (as an example) converts the SharedFlow into a StateFlow in a manner as follows:

```kotlin
var myVariable = DEFAULT_VALUE
val mySharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

val myStateFlow = mySharedFlow
                    .filter { it < 42 }
                    .asStateFlow(myVariable)// <- Convert to a StateFlow given a default value
```

This is obviously an overly simplified example, but my situation is more complex, and currently I have to invoke a function when ever a field changes, but currently I do the following:

```kotlin
myObj.onChange.collect(handler)
handler(myObj.getCurrentValue)

fun handler(data: Int) {
    // Handle data change
}
```

But I would prefer to use a Hot StateFlow and remove the need for the second function call. Especially since many consumers of this are small bits of code (mostly just a single expression) that do not need to be in their own function context, and should just be simple lambdas.

Comment: There’s the `stateIn` function for turning any Flow, including SharedFlows, into a StateFlow. But you must provide a CoroutineScope to handle doing the conversion.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for. I figured there should be a way, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tenfour04 answered my question in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672434/create-stateflow-from-sharedflow/70685332#comment124936647_70672434). The function I needed is called `stateIn()`.